# Why does Chromium crash within seconds of starting?

Tags: 11.10, chromium, debugging

When I start Chromium the program just disappears shortly after the tabs have loaded.

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 11.10 that I installed it using the wubi installer. Chromium worked fine when I first installed it. Things I can remember doing before it stopped:

- I installed 200+ ubuntu updates
- I synced chrome with my google account (bookmarks etc)
- Installed and removed eclipse

I have tried un-installing and re-installing Chromium but the problem persists.

Where can I look to diagnose the cause of the crashing?

**UPDATE - Here's what the console spits out:**

```
matt@ubuntu:~$ chromium-browser 

(chromium-browser:2023): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(chromium-browser:2023): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(chromium-browser:2023): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(chromium-browser:2023): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2023:2023:1515592300:ERROR:browser_main.cc(96)] Gtk: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -2147483648 and height 1026
chromium-browser: /build/buildd/cairo-1.10.2/src/cairo-surface.c:1287: cairo_surface_set_device_offset: Assertion `status == CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS' failed.
Aborted
matt@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: run chromium from the command line and post any errors

Comment: updated. width of something seems to be set to nonsense value

Comment: If no one has an answer, file a bug report.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/887850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

1. Start Chromium from a terminal with **`chromium-browser --password-store=basic`**
2. Log in to a web page (in my case, gmail)
3. Close Chromium
4. It should now start normally.

**Reason**

I found the bug is already reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101160). My default starting page was the gmail login page (it's password pages that cause the crash).
I was able to start the program so that it stays open with the option '--password-store=basic'. Doing this seemed to fix some problem with my synced password keystore.

Answer (score 1):

**What will help for many programms in config problems**

In cases something really doesnt work u can try not removing but Purging what means deleting also configuration files of programm.

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
```

then try after installing again start and if not still working then delete folder of configuration for that programm for specific user in this case

```
sudo rm ~/.config/chromium
```

and then starting should reset all and work.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to remove the

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

error - try

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```