# Chromium Crashes in Seconds

Tags: 16.04, chromium, crash

I changed nothing with any of my settings, extensions, etc. and Chromium decided to randomly start crashing right when I tried to reopen it after closing it. I get the following output:

```
aiman119@aiman119-HP-Pavilion-dv5-Notebook-PC:~$ chromium-browser
Using PPAPI flash.
 --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000010
#0 0x7fee452bd425 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7fee452bd80b <unknown>
#2 0x7fee455e8390 <unknown>
#3 0x56323eba2dc8 <unknown>
#4 0x56323eba5656 <unknown>
#5 0x56323eba5df9 <unknown>
#6 0x56323eba6143 <unknown>
#7 0x7fee45338821 <unknown>
#8 0x7fee452beeea base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask()
#9 0x7fee452e7e90 base::MessageLoop::RunTask()
#10 0x7fee452e997d base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask()
#11 0x7fee452ea83d <unknown>
#12 0x7fee452eb300 base::MessagePumpLibevent::Run()
#13 0x7fee452e6f15 base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()
#14 0x7fee45311628 base::RunLoop::Run()
#15 0x7fee4533de36 base::Thread::ThreadMain()
#16 0x7fee45338726 <unknown>
#17 0x7fee455de6ba start_thread
#18 0x7fee2ec8d3dd clone
  r8: 000000000000002e  r9: 00005632405f96ec r10: 0000000000000000 r11: ffffffffdedbf3f9
 r12: 00007fedc1d4bff0 r13: 0000000000000008 r14: 0000000000000008 r15: 00007fedc1d4beb0
  di: 0000000000000000  si: 00007fedc1d4beb0  bp: 00007fedc1d4bf00  bx: 00007fedc1d4beb0
  dx: 000000000000005f  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007fedd4009690  sp: 00007fedc1d4be60
  ip: 000056323eba2dc8 efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000010
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88783/why-does-chromium-crash-within-seconds-of-starting) and attempted to use that solution with the same result. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 Xenial LTS. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporary solution:-

Try open it without extensions.

```
chromium-browser --disable-extensions
```

Comment: Less obtrusive workaround and link to bug report with fixed packages here: https://askubuntu.com/a/932353/653294.

Comment: I feel like this solution is like: Don't use your browser if it constantly crashes. Sorry, but not very helpful.

Comment: @n3rd it was bug at that time which is resolved(i think) So I gave OP temp. solution. I have mention that in my answer.